# jqueryUI autoComplete, how to check if no data returned back

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I got jQueryUI AutoComplete working.  now I need to add another alert box, if there's no result returned back. I want to say

```
alert("sorry, no data found");
```

I am not sure how to add it to my existing code.

```
        $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SearchIngredients",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: request,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.map(function (value) {
                            return {
                                'label': value.Value,
                                'value': value.Value,
                                'id': value.Id
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#searchItemId").val(ui.item.id);
                $("#searchItemName").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SearchIngredients",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.length == 0){
                      alert("no data");
                    }
                    else
                    response(data.map(function (value) {
                        return {
                            'label': value.Value,
                            'value': value.Value,
                            'id': value.Id
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#searchItemId").val(ui.item.id);
            $("#searchItemName").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```